# Fast JSON/flat data server for mostly reads

Tags: database, olap, nosql

I ask this question apprehensively because it is not a pure programming question, and because I am seeking a (well informed) suggestion.

I have an analytic front end, written in JavaScript, with lots of aggregations and charting happening in the browser (dimple.js, even stats.js, ...)

I want to feed this application with JSON or delimited data from some high performance data structure server. No writes except for loading. Data will be maybe 1-5 GB in size and there could be dozens, if not hundreds concurrent readers, but only in peak hours. This data is collected from and fed by Apache Hive.

Now my question is about the selection of a database/datastore server choices for this. 
(I have pretty good command of SQL/NoSQL choices, so I am really seeking advice for the very specific requirements)

Requirements and specifications for this datastore are:

1. Mostly if not all queries will be reads, initiated by the web, JS-based front end.
2. Data can be served as JSON or flat tabular csv, psv, tsv.
3. Total data size on this store will be 1-5 GB, with possible future growth, but nothing imminent (6-12 months)
4. Data on this datastore will be refreshed/loaded into this store daily. Probably never in a real time.
5. Data will/can be accessed via some RESTful web services, Socket IO, etc.
6. Faster read access, the better. Speed matters.
7. There has to be a security/authentication method for sensitive data protection.
8. It needs to be reasonably stable, not a patching-requiring bleeding edge.
9. Liberal, open source license.

So far, my initial candidates for examination were Postgres (optimized for large cache) and Mongo. Just because I know them pretty well. 
I am also familiar with Redis, Couch.

I did not do benchmark myself, but I have seen benchmarks where Postgres was faster than Mongo (while offering JSON format).  Mongo is web-friendlier.

I am considering in-memory stores with persistence such as Redis, Aerospike, Memcached. Redis 3.0 is my favorite so far.

So, I ask you here if you have any recommendations for the production quality datastore that would fit well what I need.

Any civil and informed suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly does your data look like? Since you said CSV like exports, I'm assuming this is tabular, structured data that would usually be found in a relational database?

Some options:

**1. Don't use a database**

Given the small dataset, just serve it out of memory. You can probably spend a few hours to write a quick app with any decent web framework that just loads up the data into memory (for example, from a flat file) and then searches and returns this data in whatever format and way you need.

**2. Use an embedded database**

You can also try an embedded database like SQLite which gives you in-memory performance but with a reliable SQL interface. Since it's just a single-file database, you can have another process generate a new DB file, then swap it out when you update the data for the app.

**3. Use a full database system**

Use a regular relational database. mySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server (Express Edition) are all free and can handle that dataset easily and will just cache it all in RAM. If it's read queries, I don't see any issues with a few hundred concurrent users. You can also use memSQL community edition if you need more performance. They all support security, are very reliable, and you can't beat SQL for data access.

Use a key/value system if your data isn't relational or tabular and is more of a fit as simple values or documents. However remember KV stores aren't great at scans or aggregations and don't have joins. Memcached is just a distributed cache, don't use it for real data. Redis and Aerospike are both great key/value systems with Redis giving you lots of nice data structures to use. Mongo is good for data flexibility. Elasticsearch is a good option for advanced search-like queries.

If you're going to these database systems though, you will still need a thin app layer somewhere to interface with the database and then return the data in the proper format for your frontend.

If you want to skip that part, then just use CouchDB or Riak instead. Both are document oriented and have a native HTTP interface with JSON responses so you can consume it directly from your frontend, although this might cause security issues since anyone can see the javascript calls.

Comment: Any comments with the downvotes? what more are you looking for?